# Specify Ruby version for Chef to use

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am new to Chef as well as to Ruby, all I want is to copy a simple text file from machine A to machine B using chef-solo.

My default.rb file is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/scp'

hostname = '142.138.0.147'
username = 'someone'
password = 'someone123'

Net::SCP.start( hostname, username, :password => password ) do|scp|
  puts 'SCP Started!'
  scp.download('/home/someone/file.txt', '.')
end
```

but when running I get this error:

> FATAL: LoadError: no such file to load -- net/scp

This is because Chef is using its embedded version of Ruby not the one I installed; how can I tell Chef which Ruby version to use?

Comment: Is your system using RVM or RBEnv? Do you have multiple ruby packages installed?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what you mean by "embedded", but you need to have the right ruby version installed on the system you are executing the chef recipe.

if you want to get a tiny overview of how to handle chef, you could have a look at the railscast episode about chef-solo: http://railscasts.com/episodes/339-chef-solo-basics

Comment: my directory structure is 1)Chef-Workplace

Comment: my directory structure is 1)Chef-Workplace 2) hello 3a) config 3b) cookbooks 4b) hello world 5b) recipes; config directory contains two files 1. config.rb and 2. node.json; and in recipes one default.rb file. when i execute default.rb as a normal ruby file.. i.e. $ruby default.rb it works without error.. but when i run chef-solo it gives the error... it means it is using ruby came with it.. i.e.inbult ruby of chef

Comment: there is no such thing as a build-in-ruby in chef!

Comment: hey, the thing is it is working after i run some commands, it installed something , dont know what. hey i am absolutely new to chef and currently working on chef solo... i dont have problem with ruby.. i am good at logic, can u give me some online resources for chef solo. thanks :)

Comment: @phoet Opscode now distributes Chef as a full stack installer package for supported platforms, which includes its own Ruby. The rubygem and apt packages are also available, but the full stack package is the best way to install. http://opscode.com/chef/install